# How to display 2 rows when using Frame inside ScrollView in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have a ScrollView problem as follows: I have a list of Categories. I want it to display 2 rows of categories. I've searched for everything related to ScrollView, however I'm not seeing any results.

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
    <StackLayout Padding="12,0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Food" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Car" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Travel" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Computer" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Computer 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Computer 3" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Computer 4" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Computer 5" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I had the idea to limit the Width for the ScrollView then the categories it would drop down to 2 columns by itself, however I think it's too funny =]]]. However it still doesn't work. Anyone have any solution for this, I won't use Grid. Thank you.

**This is what I expect to display 2 rows:**

[image]

**Update**

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
    <FlexLayout Direction="Column">
        <FlexLayout FlexLayout.Grow="1">
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Food" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Car" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Travel" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </FlexLayout>
        <FlexLayout FlexLayout.Grow="2">
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Computer" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Computer 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Computer 3" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Computer 4" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Computer 5" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </FlexLayout>
    </FlexLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: use FlexLayout - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the solutions above, here is the code I customized as desired:

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
    <FlexLayout Direction="Column">
        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <FlexLayout FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label Text="Food" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label Text="Car" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label Text="Travel" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </FlexLayout>
                <FlexLayout FlexLayout.Grow="2">
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Computer" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Computer 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Computer 3" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Computer 4" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Computer 5sss" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </FlexLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FlexLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said you can do it with FlexLayout, I wrote an example for your reference.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
    <FlexLayout Direction="Column">
        <FlexLayout FlexLayout.Grow="1">
            <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Food" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Car" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Travel" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Travel 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </FlexLayout>
        <FlexLayout FlexLayout.Grow="2">
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Computer" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Computer 2" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Computer 3" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Computer 4" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="10,7" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#fff" >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Computer 5" TextColor="#333" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </FlexLayout>
    </FlexLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I have updated as your instructions, but the result is not as expected. You can see it in the update above. Thank you

Comment: The above interface is due to too much data, you may consider setting the overall to three lines.

Comment: I only want it to show 2 lines, if the input data is too much, it will show horizontal scrolling. But in my update above it doesn't show the horizontal drag even though I added: <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal"../>

Comment: I just updated my code, you can check it out. As for your problem, it's because you are using nested ScrollView, if you want to work properly, you need to set the orientation of the outer and inner layers in different directions.